# Showing AdControl only while in Portrait mode

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

There isn't enough screen real estate in my application to display an AdControl when the phone is in landscape mode. I am using the following (simplified) code in my `OnOrientationChanged` event handler to remove the AdControl from row 1 of the Grid when Landscape mode is entered and to add it back when Portrait mode is entered:

```
if (this.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft || 
    this.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight) {
    LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(myAdControl);
    LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(1);// remove row to make space
} else {
    LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions.Add(adRow);// previously constructed 80 px high RowDefinition
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myAdControl);
    Grid.SetRow(myAdControl, 1);
}
```

This seems to work in my testing, but I saw in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-adcontrol-silverlight-class%28v=msads.20%29) for the AdControl class that "Once set, the parent of an AdControl should not be changed." Is what I am doing here going to break the AdControl?

Comment: can't you just play with the visibility of the adcontrol rather than removing the whole item from grid?

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and it turns out that changing the visibility of the AdControl still leaves an empty 80px high row in the Grid. Maybe there's a way to change the row height of a Grid row dynamically?

Comment: did you make the `height in row definition` for that row as `*`? make that as `*` and `Auto` and see if you observe any difference. I guess `*` should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Grid does not recalculate the row heights when the AdControl becomes invisible, so the Adcontrol's grid row remains on the screen (showing a blank space). This blank Grid row still crowds part of my UI enough to make it unreadable.  Thanks for your suggestions, though!

Comment: @Milan In my experience, setting to `Auto` should collapse the row when its content is collapsed. `*` tells the rendering engine to expand to availble space.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe: setting the row height to Auto and the visibility of the AdControl to collapsed fixed the problem, thanks!  If you submit your suggestion as an answer, I will accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a new solution](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2013/10/28/Keeping-ads-in-the-same-location-when-the-phone-orientation-changes-to-landscape.aspx) that allows the ad control to remain stationary when the phone Orientation changes to Landscape. It uses a new control that keeps the ad control at the "bottom" even when rotated (left or right when in landscape).

The 10 second overview is to create a Grid layout and move the AdControl to the Row/Column combo that works for the orientation. [The blog](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2013/10/28/Keeping-ads-in-the-same-location-when-the-phone-orientation-changes-to-landscape.aspx) has all the detail in it.

Comment: Overall I liked this when I tried it, however it's caused some serious slow down in my app for the page it's used on.

Comment: I use this solution in my own app and have not seen any slow down. There is nothing within this logic to slow down your app. It simply listens for orientation changed

Comment: You're right, I went back and checked it all over. I've some opacity animations and they seem to be the main culprit. Constructor for the frame did have a stutter, but I moved it to an async function and that, at least, is gone.