# How do I manage ads in orientation change? (Vertical ads, WP8)

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am currently working on an app that will work in both a landscape and portrait layout. I am having some trouble dealing with rotating the ads when the orientation changes from portrait to landscape. I'm able to set up a grid and such for the ad to go vertical. I can rotate it but it gets all messed up when I do.

The reason I'm aiming for vertical is it maintains the best real-estate for me.

I'm not sure how much more detail I can offer for my situation, I just want to have the ad rotate 90-degrees so it fits to the "left or right" of the landscape screen. But a rotation forces it's grid to still be a certain width. I then put in some controls in the change function to force the grid to re size, but the add won't sit right in it's Grid after a rotation. Any suggestion or direction in this? Many thanks in advance.

Also, I was thinking to have two ad elements that simply float on the page (not in a grid). And show/hide each depending on the orientation, but that sounded stupid when I thought about it.

Comment: What ad unit are you using? I can say that PubCenter does not support vertical ads

Comment: I first was trying AdDuplex and then someone suggested that PubCenter would support them. So I decided to try it and specify the Height and Width as 480 and 80 respectively. Nothing shows up. Would another one work?

Comment: So there is no way to have my ad stay to the edge when rotated to landscape? That's really my goal. Its at the bottom of the screen in portrait, and I'd like it to stay put when the screen rotates.

Comment: There is so little space to have it vertical. It would be very hard to show content. I do not know of any ad networks that support that size, sorry...

Comment: I think I'm doing a poor job of explaining what I want to do. I want to keep the same horizontal ad, and keep it in the same position when the screen rotates. What I ended up doing is making three ads that go from collapsed to visible depending on the orientation. The problem is its three different ads, this seems like a stupid idea to me but for now it looks right. Can anyone confirm if this a proper thing to do? The three ads are floating and pre placed for when they have their orientation.

Comment: so are you wanting to keep the same "orientation" of the ad but rotate it so it fits on the side of a landscape screen?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I ended up putting three adunits on the page for each orientation, but I feel this is the wrong way to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I would let you know that I created a control to handle the rotation of the phone and keep ads stationary. Please follow this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19629533/1054961) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the ref. I'll give this a try and report back, so far the article seems to be a much better implementation of what I used to do.

Comment: One of my main issues, even doing it the way I did, was that I still had three ads on the page (no good obviously). Followed your method and it works like a charm (though I have to learn more about why it works).

Answer (score 0):

Use the PubCenter ads with the normal width and height then apply a transform to rotate it 90 degrees.

Comment: This is what I want to do, sadly it doesn't work (or at least last I checked). The problem is, once the page loads the area designated for the ad will have a width the size of the ad, once rotated it still keeeps that space despite appearing to not be using it.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a solution that helped me. I realized what I wanted was as the last commented in my posting realized; to keep an ad's orientation on rotation change.

To accomplish this one could use a LayoutTransform, however they are not available in WP8. Initially I had floating menus that switched on and off on rotation change but would be troublesome on a different sized screen.

The cleanest brute force solution I've found is to make a 3x5 (row-major) grid layout. My main page sits in the center-most grid, ads to the immediate left, right and bottom. And lastly, two filler spaces to the left-most and right-most grid:

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto "/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
            <phone:Pivot x:Name="ContentPanel">
                ...
            </phone:Pivot>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Name="AdBottom" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
            ...
        </Grid>

        <Grid Name="AdRight" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" MaxWidth="80">            
                <adduplex:AdControl x:Name="adDuplexAdRight" AppId="?????" 
                                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Margin="-200,0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <adduplex:AdControl.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform Rotation="90"/>
                </adduplex:AdControl.RenderTransform>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Name="AdLeft" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" MaxWidth="80">
            ... <As Above, just negated>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Name="FillerLeft" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="80" Visibility="Collapsed">
        </Grid>

        <Grid Name="FillerRight" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" MinWidth="80" Visibility="Collapsed">
        </Grid>            
    </Grid>
```

The reason for the Filler elements and their minimum width is to help margin overflow. Without it, you could use the Rendertransform to rotate the element, but when you tried to force it's container down to a size you wanted, it came out incorrectly. This is because the rotation happens *after* render, so without those extra padded columns to allow for overflow the element gets sliced up upon rotation.

So, doing an overflow and extending the ad's margins allows for it to show up locked in a grid instead of floating. Then I manage switching the ads' visibility and the Filler areas on a rotationchanged event.

This is the easiest solution I've had. Others can search for incorporating the Silverlight LayoutTransformer as seen [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://igrali.com/2012/09/17/layout-transform-in-windows-8-winrt-xaml/&ei=x8czUrS6C4WsiALWrICgCg&usg=AFQjCNG8kPEiB79Q3J6HEP5qdJyy28lFwg&sig2=qVxwctnSYHvLcmPEqfRa7Q). Or, if using one from a paid toolkit. This works so far for my simple app.