# Don't change control location on orientation change

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, layout, windows-phone-8

My layout XML:

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition                
            Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition
            Height="450" />
            <RowDefinition 
                Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>        

        <Image x:Name="ad" Grid.Row="0"  Source="/Images/ad1.png" />
        <Image x:Name="factImage" Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="factTime" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="28" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

The view of this layout is as follows:

[image]

`OnOrientationChange` I want the ad to remain at its position (i.e. don't rotate; only `factImage` and `factTime` should rotate). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I recently blogged about keeping ads stationary when changing the orientation of the phone. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19629533/1054961) for more information.